# How to do this problem regarding updating and deleting in PL/SQL with function and procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Problem: Utilize the Outdoor Clubs & Product database to create a procedure"ex5b_supplier_update that contains two input parameters. The first input parameter is a supplier id attribute value that is used to delete the supplier from the supplier table. The second input parameter is also another supplier id attribute value that is used to update the deleted supplier entry (of the first input parameter) in the product and purchase order table with a new supplier value. Create a boolean function "ex5b_supplier_exist" to determine if the two input parameter supplier id attribute values exists before proceeding with the data manipulations. If the suppliers do not exist, then display a message "Invalid Suppliers. Run program unit again!"

I have tried the following down below but have gotten stuck on how to setup the procedure. I am 90% sure I have the function correctly I have also provided the database table code for anyone wanting to give a helping hand.

```
create or replace function ex5b_supplier_exist (sid in varchar2)
return boolean is 
cursor product_cursor is
select supplier_id
from product
where supplier_id = sid;
product_row product_cursor%rowtype;
begin
open product_cursor;
fetch product_cursor into product_row;
if product_cursor%found then
return true;
else 
return false;
end if;
close product_cursor;
end;

create or replace procedure ex5b_supplier_update (del_supp_id in varchar2, upd_supp_id2 in varchar2) as
prod_id product.product_id%type;
begin
if ex5b_supplier_exist(del_supp_id) then
    select product_id
    into prod_id
    from product
    where product_id = prod_id;
    if supplier_id = del_supp_id then
    delete from supplier where supplier_id = del_supp_id;
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Suppliers. Run the program unit again');
    end if;
    update product
    set supplier_id = upd_supp_id
    where supplier_id = upd_supp_id;
    dbms_output.put_line('Update successful');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Invalid Suppliers. Run the program unit again');
end if;
end;
```

You are supposed to be able to do the following and receive the indicated Product IDs:

```
begin
ex5b_supplier_update('S500','S530');
end;

--This is the expected outcome 
    Product_ID
    ----------
    10010
    10011
    10013
    10020
```

Database tables:

```
drop table order_details;
drop table product_order;
drop table club_membership;
drop table purchase_order;
drop table product;
drop table customer;
drop table club_activity;
drop table sporting_clubs;
drop table supplier;

drop sequence club_sequence;
drop sequence product_id_sequence;
drop sequence customer_sequence;
drop sequence membership_sequence;
drop sequence product_order_sequence;
drop sequence supplier_sequence;
drop sequence po_sequence;

create table sporting_clubs
(club_id number(3)constraint sporting_clubs_pk primary key,
name varchar2(30),
street varchar2(30),
city varchar2(15),
state char(2),
zip number(5),
phone varchar2(10));

create table club_activity
(club_id number(3)constraint club_activity_fk references sporting_clubs,
activity varchar2(15),
constraint club_activity_pk primary key (club_id,activity));

create table supplier
(supplier_id varchar2(4) constraint supplier_pk primary key,
name varchar2(30),
street varchar2(30),
city varchar2(15),
state char(2),
zip number(5),
phone varchar2(10));

create table product
(product_id number(5) constraint product_pk primary key,
product_name varchar2(30),
quantity_in_stock number(3),
reorder_point number(2),
price number(5,2),
supplier_id varchar2(4) constraint product_fk references supplier,
reorder_qty number(2));

create table purchase_order
(po_no varchar2(4) constraint purchase_order_pk primary key,
po_date date,
product_id number(5) constraint purchase_order_fk1 references product,
quantity number(3),
supplier_id varchar2(4) constraint purchase_order_fk2 references supplier);

create table customer
(customer_id number(3) constraint customer_pk primary key,
first_name varchar2(10),
last_name varchar2(10),
street varchar2(30),
city varchar2(15),
state char(2)default 'MO',
zip number(5),
phone varchar2(10));

create table club_membership
(membership_id number(5) constraint club_membership_pk primary key,
membership_date date,
duration number(2),
amount number(4),
payment_type varchar2(5)constraint membership_payment_type_ck check ((payment_type = 'CC') or (payment_type = 'Check')),
club_id number(3) constraint club_membership_fk1 references sporting_clubs,
customer_id number(3) constraint club_membership_fk2 references customer);

create table product_order
(order_id number(4) constraint product_order_pk primary key,
order_date date,
ship_date date,
payment_type varchar2(5)constraint prod_order_payment_type_ck check ((payment_type = 'CC') or (payment_type = 'Check')),
total number (6,2),
customer_id number(3) constraint product_order_fk1 references customer);

create table order_details
(order_id number(4),
product_id number(5),
quantity number(2),
constraint order_details_pk primary key (order_id,product_id),
constraint order_details_fk1 foreign key (order_id) references product_order,
constraint order_details_fk2 foreign key (product_id) references product);


create sequence club_sequence
start with 100
increment by 10
nocache;

insert into sporting_clubs
values(club_sequence.nextval, 'Hillside Mountain Club', '1 Winona St','Wichita','KS',34342,'3163997676');
insert into sporting_clubs
values(club_sequence.nextval, 'Branson Climbing Club', '2 Sherwood Dr.','Branson','MO',65670,'4174485676');
insert into sporting_clubs
values(club_sequence.nextval, 'Cherokee Rafting Club', '44 Kent Ave.','St. Charles','MO',66572,'3147780870');
insert into sporting_clubs
values(club_sequence.nextval, 'White Plains Club', '225 Tracy St.','New York','NY',13567,'2126678090');

insert into club_activity
values(100,'Hiking');
insert into club_activity
values(100,'Climbing');
insert into club_activity
values(100,'Walking');
insert into club_activity
values(110,'Hiking');
insert into club_activity
values(110,'Climbing');
insert into club_activity
values(110,'Conservation');
insert into club_activity
values(110,'Walking');
insert into club_activity
values(120,'Conservation');
insert into club_activity
values(120,'Canoeing');
insert into club_activity
values(130,'Conservation');
insert into club_activity
values(130,'Canoeing');
insert into club_activity
values(130,'Walking');

create sequence supplier_sequence
start with 500
increment by 10
nocache;

insert into supplier
values('S'||supplier_sequence.nextval,'Hillside Ski','2717 S. Western Ave.','Los Angeles','CA',90006,'7146654959');
insert into supplier
values('S'||supplier_sequence.nextval,'Tiger Mountain','2600 S. Vermont Ave.','Los Angeles','CA',90006,'7143327878');
insert into supplier
values('S'||supplier_sequence.nextval,'Asha Outdoor','44 S. LaSalle St.','Chicago','IL',60603,'3125554678');
insert into supplier
values('S'||supplier_sequence.nextval,'Sheraton Recreation','225 Tracy St.','New York','NY',13567,'2128889569');


create sequence product_id_sequence
start with 10010
increment by 1
nocache;

insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Beginner''s Ski Boot',20,5,9.75,'S500',25);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Intermediate Ski Boot',18,5,12.99,'S500',20);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Pro Ski Boot',21,7,15.49,'S510',25);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Beginner''s Ski Pole',15,3,25.49,'S500',20);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Intermediate Ski Pole',20,3,29.99,'S520',22);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Pro Ski Pole',21,5,34.99,'S530',25);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Road Bicycle',15,4,34.95,'S520',18);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Mountain Bicycle',19,4,49.99,'S520',20);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Tire Pump',8,2,7.99,'S530',10);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Water Bottle',25,4,2.49,'S510',25);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Bicycle Tires',30,5,4.99,'S500',33);
insert into product
values(product_id_sequence.nextval,'Bicycle Helmet',23,6,10.95,'S510',25);

create sequence po_sequence
start with 11
nocache;

insert into purchase_order
values('PO'||po_sequence.nextval,to_date('5/25/12','mm/dd/yy'),10011,20,'S500');
insert into purchase_order
values('PO'||po_sequence.nextval,to_date('5/12/12','mm/dd/yy'),10015,25,'S530');
insert into purchase_order
values('PO'||po_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/25/12','mm/dd/yy'),10011,20,'S500');
insert into purchase_order
values('PO'||po_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/15/12','mm/dd/yy'),10018,10,'S530');
insert into purchase_order
values('PO'||po_sequence.nextval,to_date('7/10/12','mm/dd/yy'),10015,25,'S530');
insert into purchase_order
values('PO'||po_sequence.nextval,to_date('7/25/12','mm/dd/yy'),10019,25,'S510');


create sequence customer_sequence
start with 101
nocache;

insert into customer
values(customer_sequence.nextval,'Jack','Russell','25 North Madison Ave.','Springfield','MO',65807,'4178823434');
insert into customer
values(customer_sequence.nextval,'Betty','Trumbell','550 South Court Dr.','St. Louis','MO',63140,'3125556670');
insert into customer
values(customer_sequence.nextval,'Anil','Kaul','400 South Circle St.','Kansas City','MO',64530,'4316667070');
insert into customer
values(customer_sequence.nextval,'Tom','Wiley','1500 North Grand St.','Springfield','MO',65810,'4178825560');
insert into customer
values(customer_sequence.nextval,'Sharon','Stone','200 West Wagner St.','Springfield','MO',65807,'4176668890');

create sequence membership_sequence
start with 10010
increment by 10
nocache;

insert into club_membership
values(membership_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/12/12','mm/dd/yy'),4,200,'CC',100,101);
insert into club_membership
values(membership_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/15/12','mm/dd/yy'),2,100,'Check',110,102);
insert into club_membership
values(membership_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/21/12','mm/dd/yy'),5,250,'Check',120,103);

create sequence product_order_sequence
start with 1001
nocache;

insert into product_order
values(product_order_sequence.nextval,to_date('5/27/12','mm/dd/yy'),to_date('6/1/12','mm/dd/yy'),'CC',134.95,102);
insert into product_order
values(product_order_sequence.nextval,to_date('5/28/12','mm/dd/yy'),to_date('6/2/12','mm/dd/yy'),'CC',134.85,103);
insert into product_order
values(product_order_sequence.nextval,to_date('5/28/12','mm/dd/yy'),to_date('6/3/12','mm/dd/yy'),'Check',12.45,104);
insert into product_order
values(product_order_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/5/12','mm/dd/yy'),to_date('6/10/12','mm/dd/yy'),'CC',44.43,105);
insert into product_order
values(product_order_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/6/12','mm/dd/yy'),to_date('6/8/12','mm/dd/yy'),'Check',52.48,103);
insert into product_order
values(product_order_sequence.nextval,to_date('6/8/12','mm/dd/yy'),to_date('6/12/12','mm/dd/yy'),'CC',131.94,104);


insert into order_details values(1001,10011,2);
insert into order_details values(1001,10015,3);
insert into order_details values(1002,10011,5);
insert into order_details values(1002,10016,2);
insert into order_details values(1003,10019,5);
insert into order_details values(1004,10018,3);
insert into order_details values(1004,10011,1);
insert into order_details values(1004,10019,3);
insert into order_details values(1005,10017,1);
insert into order_details values(1005,10019,1);
insert into order_details values(1005,10021,1);
insert into order_details values(1006,10012,4);
insert into order_details values(1006,10015,2);

commit;
```

Comment: You can't have two parameters to a procedure which both have the same name.

Comment: So how would I go about having the two input variables be the supplier_id like the question is asking me to do? One for deleting the supplier_id and one for updating the supplier_id for product and purchase_order.

Comment: Make names of parameters different.  
(supplier_id1 in varchar2, supplier_id2 in varchar2)

Comment: Cool thanks I have updated my procedure code on here in terms of what I have so far!

Comment: I'd advise to use better names for the function parameters. Something like curry_supp_id and new_supp_id. Then its clear what the parameters are.

Comment: I just edited it to be more clear so that the first input is indicated to delete(del) and the second input is to update(upd).

Comment: Why do all coursework examples use `char`? It's really best to stick with the standard `varchar2`. Bonus points for not coding in uppercase though :)

Comment: idk why coursework does that, I try to stick with the standard as well and I also try not to do uppercase coding mainly because I don’t like the way it looks.

Answer (score 0):

First the `ex5b_supplier_exist` function. To find out if a `SUPPLIER_ID` exists, you need to query the `SUPPLIER` database table, not the `PRODUCT` table. Also, no need to define a cursor, a simple `count(*)` query will suffice and also avoids the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception if the supplied `SUPPLIER_ID` does not exist...

```
create or replace function ex5b_supplier_exist(sid supplier.supplier_id%type)
return boolean
is
  l_count  pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_count
    from supplier
   where supplier_id = sid;
  return l_count > 0;
end ex5b_supplier_exist;
```

Now the `ex5b_supplier_update` procedure. Since you are removing a `SUPPLIER_ID`, you need to first update any database tables that reference that ID. If you don't, you will get an error...

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (PRODUCT_FK) violated - child record found

Hence procedure `ex5b_supplier_update` must first update tables `PRODUCT` and `PURCHASE_ORDER` since they both may contain rows with the `SUPPLIER_ID` you are about to delete from the `SUPPLIER` table.

```
create or replace procedure ex5b_supplier_update(del_supp_id supplier.supplier_id%type
                                                ,upd_supp_id supplier.supplier_id%type)
as
begin
  if ex5b_supplier_exist(del_supp_id) and ex5b_supplier_exist(upd_supp_id) then
    update product
       set supplier_id = upd_supp_id
     where supplier_id = del_supp_id;
  --
    update purchase_order
       set supplier_id = upd_supp_id
     where supplier_id = del_supp_id;
  --
    delete from supplier
     where supplier_id = del_supp_id;
  --
    dbms_output.put_line('update successful');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('invalid suppliers. run the program unit again');
  end if;
end ex5b_supplier_update;
```

Comment: If I do that procedure though it will come out with the suppliers I need being invalid and it wont print out the product_ids with those associated supplier_ids.

Comment: This is a typically re-point problem where ALL the foreign keys need to be updated before you can delete the original parent row. If you don't do essentially as @Abra suggests your procedure will never run successfully, it will receive a FK violation when you attempt to delete the original parent.  You are however correct that it'll not be able to display the updates product ids as it currently stands. For that You need to check out the "Returning" Clause of the update statement, and since multiple products may be update check out "Returning ... bulk collect'

Comment: @BrokenCoder I guess I missed that part of your question where you are required to print out the product IDs. Can you reply to this comment and quote that part, please?

Comment: @Abra I have updated the post to show what code you are supposed to run as well as the expected output. I have put it in between the code I provided and the database tables.